# ¿Cambiar los colores por defecto de bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

estoy haciendo un sitio web usando una plantilla de bootstrap la cual es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El tema es que estado cambiando los archivos CSS para que la página sea de color negro. Pero no importa cuantos valores cambie/borre, los colores siguen exactamente iguales, ¿Alguien sabe porqué pasa esto?

A continuación muestro parte el HTML

```html
 <!-- Theme CSS -->
  <link href="css/freelancer.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body id="page-top" bgcolor=" #000000">

  <!-- Navigation -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-secondary text-uppercase fixed-top" id="mainNav">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" href="#page-top">DUAL EFFECTS</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right text-uppercase font-weight-bold bg-primary text-white rounded" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        Menu
        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item mx-0 mx-lg-1">
            <a class="nav-link py-3 px-0 px-lg-3 rounded js-scroll-trigger" href="#portfolio">Screenshots</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item mx-0 mx-lg-1">
            <a class="nav-link py-3 px-0 px-lg-3 rounded js-scroll-trigger" href="#about">Información</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item mx-0 mx-lg-1">
            <a class="nav-link py-3 px-0 px-lg-3 rounded js-scroll-trigger" href="#contact">Contacto</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <!-- Masthead -->
  <header class="masthead bg-primary text-white text-center">
    <div class="container d-flex align-items-center flex-column">

      <!-- Masthead Avatar Image -->
      <img class="masthead-avatar mb-5" src="img/logotypo.png" alt="">

      <!-- Masthead Heading -->
      <h1 class="masthead-heading text-uppercase mb-0">TORMENTED SOULS</h1>

      <!-- Icon Divider -->
      <div class="divider-custom divider-light">
        <div class="divider-custom-line"></div>
        <div class="divider-custom-icon">
          <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="divider-custom-line"></div>
      </div>

      <!-- Masthead Subheading -->
      <p class="masthead-subheading font-weight-light mb-0">[ESLOGAN]</p>

    </div>
  </header>
```

Aquí un ejemplo del archivo css

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  #mainNav {
    padding-top: 1.5rem;
    padding-bottom: 1.5rem;
    transition: padding-top 0.3s, padding-bottom 0.3s;
  }
  #mainNav .navbar-brand {
    font-size: 1.75em;
    transition: font-size 0.3s;
  }
  #mainNav .navbar-nav {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  #mainNav .navbar-nav > li.nav-item > a.nav-link.active {
    color: #fff;
    background: #000000;
  }
  #mainNav .navbar-nav > li.nav-item > a.nav-link.active:active, #mainNav .navbar-nav > li.nav-item > a.nav-link.active:focus, #mainNav .navbar-nav > li.nav-item > a.nav-link.active:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: #000000;
  }
  #mainNav.navbar-shrink {
    padding-top: 0.5rem;
    padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
  }
  #mainNav.navbar-shrink .navbar-brand {
    font-size: 1.5em;
  }
}
```

Como se puede ver, se supone que, por ejemplo, la barra navbar debería ser de color negro, sin embargo el color no cambia...

No se si esto afecte, pero subiré tambien una imagen con los CSS que yo creo son los que afectan el diseño del sitio:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En el `html` estás haciendo referencia al archivo minificado `<link href="css/freelancer.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`, cambia esa línea por esta `<link href="css/freelancer.css" rel="stylesheet">`. Con eso basta para que te tome los cambios que hagas en el archivo `freelancer.css`... ahhh, y borra la caché de tu navegador.

Comment: ME SIRVIO

ME SIRVIO

MUCHAS GRACIAS AMIGO MUCHAS GRACIAS